# Why can't plastic be used as a building material for cities?

Tags: plastic

There are a lot of items that require a lot of material. But this material should not be expensive.
We can fill large items with recycled plastic. No complex processing technology is needed here, but only coarse mechanical grinding.

Examples of things we can make from recycled plastic: benches, gates, hatches, street lamps, bricks for non-residential premises, roof, insulation of facades, advertising signs, trash cans or even cobblestones...

Do our cities already have all the necessary things?
Definitely not... So the question is, why is there still a problem with plastic waste?
Why not put all the plastic in the decoration of cities?

In my city, public things are made of metal and stone, and the problem of plastic is still acute. Tons of plastic could be used to decorate the city. So what is the point here?

Comment: I have often seen park benches and rubbish bins made of recycled plastic. You know this because there is a sign proudly informing you of the fact.

Comment: Why do you think there is still a problem with plastic waste? If all the garbage went only to building materials, then this problem should have disappeared long ago.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! We have a related question: [Would it be possible to recycle all plastic into bricks and use them for building or insulation](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/3206/99)

Comment: @THelper Thank you! I read this question before, but this is not an answer to my question. There they offer to make bricks from plastic, and I suggest using plastic as a filler. And the main question: if it is theoretically possible (bricks, or a filler), then why is there still a problem with plastic? There must be some good reason

Comment: The demand for recycled plastic is not necessarily the issue so much as the supply. For some types of plastic, the demand for recycled plastic is already greater than the demand for new plastic, making new plastic a cheaper option. Making these items out of recycled plastic won't necessarily increase the amount of plastic being recycled. Additionally, recycling plastic is energy-costly, making recycled plastic not a great choice from an economic or climate-change perspective.

Comment: 'Building materials' and 'plastics' are both compendium categories, both contain materials made using many different methods that sometimes clash. Example, wall cladding needs to be fire-proof. Many plastics are not. How to separate them economically?